# .NET Core Publish Compilation Errors

Tags: c#, .net-core, build, publish

I have a .NET Core 2.2 project that builds in both Debug and Release configuration just fine. However, the build fails when I try and publish the project.

`Startup.cs(26,16): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Startup.cs(35,39): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IServiceCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Startup.cs(29,24): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\ConsentController.cs(37,13): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ILogger<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\ConsentController.cs(30,26): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ILogger<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I've tried cleaning the solution. Anyone else seen similar behaviour?

Comment: We need to see more details about your project configuration to be able to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this from terminal:

```
dotnet publish
```

Comment: Thanks! Works, but no idea why it's still failing in the IDE.

Comment: Try closing and opening the visual studio again. Worked for me.